# Unable to open designer form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, designer

I recently had problems opening my Designer View of a form hat acts as launcher for all the other forms.

The solutions I found according to that suggest to delete the .RESX files which helped for some days now (always had to delete RESX before debuging the program) today, after trying to debug another time I got stuck with this screen:

[image]

This seems to be caused by me deleting the resx files.

I can not find anything according to this online.

I tried to rebuild the project, getting the deleted file(s) back from the paperbin but nothing seems to help right here and I just do not understand what this error message is supposed to tell me...

```
bei System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.NativeMethods.ThrowOnFailure(Int32 hr, Int32[] expectedHRFailure)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.DesignerDocDataService.GetFileDocData(String fileName, FileAccess access, String createTemplate, Boolean addToHostList, Boolean nestedItem)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomProvider.OnParseBegin(TextReader reader)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomParser.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.MergedCodeDomParser.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeParser.Parse(TextReader stream)
bei System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.Parse(TextReader codeStream)
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
bei System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
```

(Nothing in Errorlist)

Comment: Revert back from SVN/Git to the previously working version.

Comment: "Revert back from SVN/Git to the previously working version." what do you mean by that ? allready did exchange the files with an backup from yesterday but it does not help

Comment: The single most helpful solution to these kind of Designer errors to me was/is to debug one instance of Visual Studio with another instance of Visual Studio. Thus getting detailed exception info whenever such an exception occurred.

Comment: Do you use any third party controls from Telerik or Syncfusion or something like that?

Comment: It seems that you're using a COM/ActiveX control. If so, try temporarily remove that, rebuild and see if it succeeds, and then add it again.